# Qt and threaded local server , why is the whole UI stuck?

Tags: sockets, unix, networking, qt4, qthread

Here's a minimal test case , I tried to start a local domain server , with `QThread` , so the UI shouldn't  stuck.  But when it's starting , i saw `Listening` output from qDebug() , but the widgets added from form editor totally disappeared , everything went slow (e.g resizing the window) , if i remove `thread.start()` , the UI shows up and functions well.

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    connect (&thread , SIGNAL(started()) , SLOT(setupServer()));
    thread.start();
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::setupServer()
{
    struct sockaddr_un address;
    int socket_fd, connection_fd;
    socklen_t address_length;

    // create socket .. and create socket file ..
    // bind ...
    // listen ..

    qDebug() << "Listening ..";

    while((connection_fd = ::accept(socket_fd,
                                    (struct sockaddr *) &address,
                                    &address_length)) > -1)
    {
        qDebug() << "Got an connection.";
        ::close (connection_fd);
    }

    // close socket and remove the socket file
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [accept(2)](http://linux.die.net/man/2/accept) syscall is by default blocking. You should take advantage of the multiplexing syscall [poll(2)](http://linux.die.net/man/2/poll) or [select(2)](http://linux.die.net/man/2/select) used by the QApplication's [exec](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qcoreapplication.html#exec) event loop.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1754256/841108) and use the [QtNetwork](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qtnetwork.html) module.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your setupServer is always called in gui thread. Deliver your own QThread based class and reimplement run method. Put your "setupServer" code inside